# Show battery percentage on Nexus 7 (Jelly Bean)

Tags: battery, 4.1-jelly-bean

Is there a (preferably built-in) way to show the remaining battery percentage in the status bar on the Nexus 7 (4.1.1)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Jelly Bean

Unfortunately, there is no setting that you can enable to show battery percentage on the system icons tray. Without using an app, all you have is:

1. Battery indicator on the top right corner of your screen.
2. Access to the battery settings, level and usage details:

   Go to: Settings > Device > Battery

   [image]

---

### App

Using the [Battery](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.macropinch.pearl) app by MacroPinch available from Google Play Store, you are able to get the percentage on your status bar:

[image]